# Module view in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've found this msdn blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/13/did-you-know-how-to-optimize-your-code-for-a-build-290.aspx

How can I get this module view in VS10?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This window is available during debugging.

Set breakpoint in some code line and start debugging. When debugger breaks, select Debug - Windows - Modules in the main Visual Studio menu.